# How to get rid of files which end in .Identifier in Laravel

Tags: docker, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I cloned a laravel-8 sail project via gitlab but everywhere in every folder which containing files there is a file which ends in `.Identifier`
I don't know where they come from. There may be 1000 files like this in the project.

My question is:

- How can I get rid of those files which endr with `.Identifier`?
- Is there some kind of Ubuntu or docker command that searches the entire project for such file which ends in `.Identifier` and then deletes them?
- Maybe phpStorm has such a function?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux machine, then open terminal in you project folder and run `rm *.Identifier`. And if you are on Windows machine then open command prompt in your project folder and run `del *.Identifier`. This will do the trick for you.